# Selenium Webdriver UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation, testng

I am getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'HOME', ip: '10.1.11.121', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:299)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at com.tests.TestClass2.test2(TestClass2.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    ... 44 more
```

My Environment:

```
OS:       Windows 7
JDK:      javac 1.8.0_31
FireFox:  ESR 31.4.0
Eclipse:  4.4.2.20150219-0708
Selenium: selenium-2.45.0
Testng:   6.8.6.20141201_2240
```

I am using a Testing suite file to run 2 classes (TestClass1 & TestClass 2). It throws above error when invoking browser for 2nd class. Here is my complete Project

Base Class:

```
public class BaseClass {

    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static boolean implicitwait(long time) {
        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static boolean LaunchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        implicitwait(50000);
        try {
             System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin",
             "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
            driver.navigate().to("https:google.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            implicitwait(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Launching Browser & Navigating To Page");
        return true;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void CloseBrowser() {
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Closing Browser");
    }
}

Test Class:

@Test
public class TestClass extends BaseClass {

    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("TEST 1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("ABC");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    }
}


Test Class2

@Test
public class TestClass2 extends BaseClass {

    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("TEST 2");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("DEF");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    }
}
```

I would super appreciate if someone can let me know what I am doing wrong

My Testng.xml:

```
<test name="Run Test Class In Firefox">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.tests.TestClass" />
        <class name="com.tests.TestClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: Using BeforeSuite and AfterSuite didn't help, someone please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` instead of `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`

```
@AfterClass
public void CloseBrowser() {
    driver.close();
    System.out.println("Closing Browser");
}
```

Basically closing the current browser instance after the first class and thus, the driver instance is not valid to run the tests for next class. You can test this by commenting out the `@AfterClass`

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_execution_procedure.htm)

**EDIT**

[Video](http://screencast.com/t/WU03Do5J4iqb)

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/safrrhmn/b614f6eb7ab92b1b282f)

Comment: Saifur, Thanks for the quick reply, As per your recommendation, I used BeforeSuite and AfterSuite but that didn't work as expected. What happening is this: 

Browser get opene by 1st test case, then actions of both tests are being performed together. As per my code, 1st test should type ABC & close browser, but it's typing "ABCDEF" & then browser closes Please let me know what I what I am doing wrong :( , I want to open/close browser for each testcase. My testng.xml says:
 <test >
  <classes>
   <class name="com.tests.TestClass" />
   <class name="com.tests.TestClass2" />
  </classes>
 </test>

Comment: I am honestly unclear now what you are trying to do. Share same instance in between both classes?

Comment: I just want each class to invoke & close browser respectively. The code I have (above) is very simple. I just can't invoke & close browser respectively using testng.xml . I just provide my testng.xml code above

Comment: I thought you want to use same browser instance everywhere. But, if you want to open and close in each class then `BeforeClass` and `AfterClass` are good. Just try `driver.quit();` instead of `driver.close();`

Comment: I wouldn't have asked something if it was that simple. Matter of fact I have tried all 3 option but none works:

driver.quit();
or
driver.close();
or
WindowsUtils.tryToKillByName("firefox.exe");
WindowsUtils.tryToKillByName("javaw.exe");

Comment: Seeking some help desperately :( I dearly hope not that  I have been hit with a dead end.